# Select only one element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 3 panel accordion and when user clicks a link on page it opens whichever accordion link name they click. The accordions also have a + glyhpicon when closed and then a - glyhpicon when open signaling "open" or "close"....My problem is when they click the link to add the "open" each glyhpicon changes and not just the one on say the third panel.

I've got the basic jquery selector working but not the plus minus functionality

JQUERY:

```
  $('.scrollLink').click(function(){
        $('#panel3').addClass('collapse in');
        $('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#panel1" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel2" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel3" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
```

One of the panels HTML:

```
<h4 class="panel-title"> <a href="#panel2" id="#panel2" 
  data-parent="#accordion" data- 
toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="true"><i 
 class="floatright glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i><b>Breathe</b> . 
 </a> </h4>
```

Comment: I think `this` will fix the problem

Comment: Look at the example provided with jQuery : https://api.jquery.com/click/
They are using ```this``` to select the element that had fired your click() function

Comment: You should target the glyphicon that is inside your panel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.
Firstly, clear the collapse in and glyphicon-minus to all the scroll link first, then add the collapse in and glyphicon-minus to the selected one.

```
    $('.scrollLink').click(function(){
        $(.scrollLink).removeClass('collapse in');
        $(.scrollLink).children(".glyphicon").removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
        $(this).addClass('collapse in');
        $(this).children(".glyphicon").addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want. Note that I tweaked your `id` for each of the headings, as they shouldn't really have a '#' in them. The lines below are the key bits, all the jquery has been commented in the demo below.

```
// Determine panel id from href
panel = $(this).attr("href");

// Add the -minus class to the correct panel
$(panel).find('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
```

I'm not sure why you've got the following line, you shouldn't be targeting a specific panel, but rather the panel that is currently active.

```
$('#panel3').addClass('collapse in');
```

Hopefully this helps, let me know if it wasn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
$('.scrollLink').click(function() {

  // Why are you doing this to a specific tab?
  // You should make this generic and add it to only the panel that is currently active
  $('#panel3').addClass('collapse in');
  
  // Remove current -minus classes
  $(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus");

  // Determine panel id from href
  panel = $(this).attr("href");

  // Add the -minus class to the correct panel
  $(panel).find('.glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-minus');

});
```

```css
.glyphicon-minus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#panel1" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel2" class="scrollLink">Test</a>
<a href="#panel3" class="scrollLink">Test</a>

<h4 class="panel-title">
  <a href="#panel1" id="panel1" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="floatright glyphicon">x</i> <b>Panel 1</b>
  </a>
</h4>

<h4 class="panel-title">
  <a href="#panel2" id="panel2" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
    <i class="floatright glyphicon">x</i> <b>Panel 2</b>
  </a>
</h4>

<h4 class="panel-title">
  <a href="#panel3" id="panel3" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="floatright glyphicon">x</i> <b>Panel 3</b>
  </a>
</h4>
```